# Open XML files from PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I try to open an XML which is housed in the MySQL database. The field is of type "longblob" but I get the following error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"
```

My code:

```
public function select(){
               $this -> conect = new conect("root", "....");
               $data = $this -> conect -> conexion();           
               $dbquery = $data -> prepare("SELECT * 
                                            FROM FILE 
                                            ORDER BY ID
                                            LIMIT 1
                                          ");
               $dbquery -> execute();     
               $rows = $dbquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
               $string = $rows['BYTES'];

               $stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
               fwrite($stream, $string);
               rewind($stream);

              echo stream_get_contents($stream);

            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) you see that `simplexml_load_file()` expects a *file* as argument and attempts to open that file. It does *not* accept xml payload directly.

Easiest would be to use a stream to solve this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but would you recommend for this?

Comment: Well, as written: take a look at streams. Maybe have a start here, that should give you the idea: http://evertpot.com/222/

Comment: I look at my upgrade, I'm wrong? sorry am a newbie... :(